# How to convert content of InMemoryUploadedFile to string

Tags: django, python-3.x

Does anyone know how to convert content of uploaded file (`InMemoryUploadedFile`) in Django2 to string?

I want to know how to write the following `convert2string()`:

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
my_xml = convert2string(uploaded_file)  # TODO write method(convert to xml string)
obj = MyObject()
parser = MyContentHandler(obj)
xml.sax.parseString(my_xml, parser)  # or xml.sax.parse(convertType(uploaded_file), parser)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `str(uploaded_file.read())` to convert `InMemoryUploadedFile` to `str`

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
print(type(uploaded_file))  # <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
print(type(uploaded_file.read()))  # <class 'bytes'>
print(type(str(uploaded_file.read())))  # <class 'str'>
```

**UPDATE-1**
Assuming you are uploading a text file (`.txt`,`.json` etc) as below,

```
my text line 1
my text line 2
my text line 3
```

then your view be like,

```
def my_view(request):
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
    str_text = ''
    for line in uploaded_file:
        str_text = str_text + line.decode()  # "str_text" will be of `str` type
    # do something
    return something
```

Comment: Thanks, but `str(uploaded_file.read())` does not work with `ValueError`, `unknown url type: "b''"`.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is raising from that line?

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA Updated the answer

Comment: Your code works fine after adding str_text = '' above `for line in uploaded_file:` and changing from `str_text = line.decode()` to `str_text = str_text + line.decode()`. Thank you!

Comment: glad to know that :)

Answer (score 3):

file_in_memory -> InMemoryUploadedFile

```
file_in_memory.read().decode() -> txt output
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read file data as a list, then you can try out the following code:

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES['file'] 
file_data = uploaded_file.read().decode().splitlines()  # get each line data as list item
```

Comment: Who said anything about a list??