# How to process a file uploaded using a form in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, forms, file

I built a form with a FileField in order to upload file to be processed. Strangely it seem that file is closed before I can do anything with in the view. I encounter a  ValueError after validating the form:

> "I/O operation on closed file"

I can see that file is properly detected but closed when attempting to read it.

Note: Django version 2.2.25.

**forms.py**

```
class FileImportForm(forms.Form):
    headers = ["lastname","firstname","gender","title","entity","email","company","address","phone"]
    file = forms.FileField(label='CSV file',validators=[CsvFileValidator(headers)])
    
    def clean_file(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data['file']
        return file
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def file_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = FileImportForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            if request.FILES['file']:
                file_post = request.FILES['file']
                # Offending line below (I/O operation on closed file)
                file_content = file_post.read().decode('UTF-8')

                return redirect("/foo")
    else:
        form = FileImportForm()
    
    return render(request,"file_import.html", { 'form': form })
```

How to properly process uploaded file (read, etc..)?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you didn't open your file properly. Here's the working way:

```py
file_post = request.FILES['file']
f = open(file_post, "w")
```

As python's file operation also comes with a read-only method, you cannot do `file_content = file_post.read().decode('UTF-8')` directly because you didn't make this file writable.

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp).

**EDIT**

As the upload file type may be incorrect, more conversions are needed. Something like:

```py
def my_view(request):
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
    str_text = ''
    for line in uploaded_file:
        str_text = str_text + line.decode()  # "str_text" will be of `str` type
    # do something
    return something
```

[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521674/how-to-convert-content-of-inmemoryuploadedfile-to-string/50521963#50521963)

Comment: This doesn't work, it throws a TypeError exception "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile". Type is not one of expected types for open.

Comment: Probably you should consider some other way then. As the demo stuck with `txt` files, probably `InMemoryUploadedFile` is another type that doesn't fit with python's rules

Comment: I just edited my answer. Can you make use of my edit?

Comment: Exception "I/O operation on closed file" this time. Somehow raw file content need to be converted.

Comment: The second reference I put up there had this: `uploaded_file.read()`. If you're trying to actually write the file, you might be looking for something else.

Comment: No write operation here, offending line throwing "I/O operation on closed file" is "for line in uploaded_file". I finally figured out how to convert the file without throwing an exception using io.TextIOWrapper(file_post)

Comment: Strangely I can't get read() method from io.TextIOWrapper object (converted from InMemoryUploadedFile to work correctly), it also throws "I/O operation on closed file" exception